# How to open new HTML.TWIG with ajax post method in symfony

Tags: ajax, redirect, post, twig, symfony

I'll try to explain the situation, I want by calling AJAX post to be able to open new html.twig template and load all the data that was return to the callback of the ajax method. To be honest I have no idea how that can be achieved.

My controller

```
/**
 * @Route("/Datasheet", name="DatasheetPage")
 *
 * @return JsonResponse|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function QCCAction(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        $part_family = $request->request->get('Part_Family');
        $QCE = $request->request->get('QCE');
        if($part_family == "DSUB")
        {
            $em =$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            /** @var $repository \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager */
            $query = $em->createQuery(
                '
            SELECT
            qce
            FROM
            AppBundle:QCE_SUBD qce
            WHERE
             qce.qCE LIKE :QCE

            '
            )->setParameters(array(
                'QCE' => '%'.$QCE.'%',
            ));
            $QCADS = $query->getArrayResult();


            return new JsonResponse(json_encode($QCADS));

        }

    }

return $this->render('MyIndex/QCC_DATASHEETS.html.twig');
}
```

Here the found values are return to the post,

```
function generate_QCEs() {
$.post("/app_dev.php/Datasheet" ,
    {
        Part_Family: 'DSUB',
        QCE : 'DSUB_PWR_5_P_-_CBL_QLH_4X1.0QMMTC'

    } ,
    function (data)
    {
        $('#QCE_HEADLINE').append('<h3>QCE:DSUB_PWR_5_P_-_CBL_QLH_4X1.0QMMTC</h3>');

        var obj =  JSON.parse(data);
       // console.log(obj);
       var Cable = obj[0].descriptionCables;
       var Gender = obj[0].gender;
        var partFamily =obj[0].partFamily;
       var FamilyType = obj[0].familyType;
       var Contacts  = obj[0].numOfContacts;
        MATING_QCEs(Cable, Gender, partFamily, FamilyType, Contacts);
    }
);
```

}

So basically what I'm seeking is, how I could redirect to another twig and at the same time upload all the values to it. 
for Example

```
 $('#QCE_HEADLINE').append('<h3>QCE:DSUB_PWR_5_P_-_CBL_QLH_4X1.0QMMTC</h3>');
```

The AJAX call needs redirect me and update Datasheet.html.twig while my call is made from another twig template......